# Cast to the pointer to array of structs

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer to the array of structs:

```
struct myStruct (*str_ptr)[];
```

I try to assign to it a value i have in another pointer which type is (uint8_t*)
When I do:

```
uint8_t* ptr2;
ptr2 = (some memory adress);
str_ptr = ptr2;
```

I get a warning:
`"assignment to 'myStruct (*)[]' {aka 'struct <anonymous> (*)[]'} from incompatible pointer type 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"`

Obvious solution to the problem is to cast **ptr2** to the type of **str_ptr**... and I tried many configurations, but all casts I can think of returns in compiler error.
Anyone know how to cast a pointer to the "pointer to the array of structs"?

Edit:
Sorry, I will try to describe what I'm trying to do here.
I have some data on external memory, and firstly I declare memory for it:

```
ptr2 = malloc(data_size);
```

Then fill it with some data using memcpy (thats why I want it to be (uint8_t*) type).
Lastly, I try to assign my pointer to the array of structs to the place where the data starts, so i can access it by typing `(*str_ptr)[3].field` for example.

Comment: A typical pointer to an array of structs (or anything, for that matter) would be a simple pointer to struct, like `struct myStruct *str_ptr;`. And the best way to assign to your struct from untyped memory is with `memcpy()`, e.g. `memcpy(str_ptr, ptr2, sizeof(*str_ptr);`.

Comment: You can't wildly convert from `uint8_t*` to another pointer type, simple as that. Casting means you might invoke undefined behavior = compiler error or no compiler error, it's still a bug. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Lundin Such problems typically arise when data is received by some hardware.

Comment: @AdrianMole I believe the Linux kernel performed a lot of such casts and simply switched gcc to non-anal mode by optioning off strict aliasing. Linus famously ranted about compilers making these assumptions, but that was half a lifetime ago. Not sure what the current state of affairs is -- given how natural it is to impose a layout on data which you know has that layout, and how well it actually fits the original loose C type paradigm I'd bet it's still common. It feels a lot like C was meant to not only allow but *facilitate* such casts.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10147399

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica I receive data from external FRAM memory. Also, all structs I use are with `__attribute__((packed))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers to arrays can present tricky C syntax issues. However, a very strong hint for the type of cast required to avoid a compiler warning is given in the message you have quoted: `"assignment to 'myStruct (*)[]'` …

However, that type isn't *quite* complete, because you also need the `struct` keyword.

So, your warning-free cast assignment would be like this:

```c
str_ptr = (struct myStruct(*)[])ptr2;
```

Comment: I was looking at it and I'm pretty sure I tried this cast, but must made some typo and just think "It does not work, there should be some other way". Thank you for your answer anyway!